# How do you merge branch such that the new commits are on top?

Tags: git

Suppose I have branch `A`. Now I create new branch `B` from `A` and make some commits. Suppose during this time `A` got a bunch of commits as well. Is there a way to merge those new commits to `B` such that the commits I made on `B` will be that the top ?

To illustrate:

```
A -> a1 -> a2 -- B created here -- -> a3 -> a4
                 B -> a1 -> a2 -> b1 -> b2
```

How do I merge such that `B` ends up like

```
 B -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> b1 -> b2
```

Comment: I think this is a dupe.  It looks like a standard `rebase` question.  Is there something else to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to `rebase`, not `merge`

When on `B`, do

```
git rebase A
```

This won't affect the A branch, but it will rewrite the recent history of the B branch.

Beforehand, you had

```
... -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> A
              \--> b1 -> b2 -> B
```

and after you will have:

```
... -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> A
                          \--> b1 -> b2 -> B
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rebase`

My typical workflow, which includes working in branches and merging into master is:

```
git status # Make sure I am in the master branch, "git checkout master" if not
git pull
git checkout -b new_branch # New branch called new_branch
# do the work, tests, etc.
git add .
git commit
git checkout master
git pull # Get the very latest master
git checkout my_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge my_branch  
git push master
```